# MySQL query inner join SUM

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, case, union

I have two tables "furesz" has all the incoming cubic meters by day. I have a "maglya" with the out come cubic meter by day. I want to make a table wher each day the in put and the out put cubic sum is shown

furesz:

| wood | length | cubic | date | machine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A-001 | 2.5 | 0,885 | 2022-02-22 | mebor1 |
| A-001 | 2.5 | 0,655 | 2022-02-22 | mebor1 |
| A-003 | 2.5 | 0,785 | 2022-02-23 | mebor1 |

maglya:

| wood | width | cubic | date | machine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A-006 | 36 | 0,585 | 2022-02-22 | mebor1 |
| A-006 | 58 | 0,355 | 2022-02-22 | mebor1 |
| A-008 | 37 | 0,685 | 2022-02-23 | mebor1 |

I tried to do it with inner join but it not work out! What should I change or do to get the following output:

| Day | A-001 sum(in) | A-006 sum (out) | A-003 sum (in) | A-008 sum (out) | total sum (in) | total sum (out) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-22 | 1.540 | 0.940 | 0 | 0 | 1.540 | 0.940 |
| 2022-02-23 | 0 | 0 | 0.785 | 0.685 | 0.785 | 0.685 |

```
SELECT MONTH(date) AS month,    
SUM(IF(wood='A-001',cubic,0)) sum_nyar,
SUM(IF(wood='A-003',cubic,0)) sum_tölgy,
SUM(IF(wood='A-004',cubic,0)) sum_vtölgy,
SUM(IF(wood='A-018',cubic,0)) AS sum_cser,
SUM(cubic) AS sum_full,
FROM furesz
UNION
SELECT MONTH(date) AS month,    
SUM(IF(wood='A-006',cubic,0)) sum_m_nyar,
SUM(IF(wood='A-008',cubic,0)) sum_m_tölgy,
SUM(IF(wood='A-009',cubic,0)) sum_m_vtölgy,
SUM(IF(wood='A-017',cubic,0)) AS sum_m_cser,
SUM(cubic) AS sum_m_full,
FROM maglya
WHERE machine='mebor1'
GROUP BY month
```

Comment: No! If you have furesz, you have maglya also

Comment: you want a union, not a join.  though if you group each day in subqueries (one for each table), you could just join those

Comment: I'made it with UNION but the maglya comes in a row and the furesz in a nother row. I have edit my post with the new query.

Comment: if you add output of `show create table yourtablename` for both tables (as text, not images), it would be much easier to answer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` first to get all the rows of both tables and then use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT month,
       SUM(CASE WHEN col = 1 AND wood = 'A-001' THEN cubic ELSE 0 END) `A-001 sum(in)`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN col = -1 AND wood = 'A-006' THEN cubic ELSE 0 END) `A-006 sum(out)`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN col = 1 AND wood = 'A-003' THEN cubic ELSE 0 END) `A-003 sum(in)`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN col = -1 AND wood = 'A-008' THEN cubic ELSE 0 END) `A-008 sum(out)`,
       .................................................................................,
       SUM(CASE WHEN col = 1 THEN cubic ELSE 0 END) `total sum(in)`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN col = -1 THEN cubic ELSE 0 END) `total sum(out)`
FROM (
  SELECT MONTH(date) month, wood, cubic, 1 col FROM furesz
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MONTH(date) month, wood, cubic, -1 col FROM maglya WHERE machine = 'mebor1'
) t
GROUP BY month;
```